# assistance creating a SQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, join

Somewhat new to SQL queries and I need a little help with my join.

I am supplied with **gid**

For each of these I need to grab **name** from table **wp_ngg_gallery**

then join in table **wp_ngg_pictures** and grab field **filename** limit **1** order **DESC** by field **imagedate**

[image]

[image]

Anyone able to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm going to guess:

```
select wp_ngg_gallery.name, wp_ngg_pictures.filename
from wp_ngg_gallery, wp_ngg_pictures
where wp_ngg_pictures.galleryid = wp_ngg_gallery.gid
order by wp_ngg_pictures.imagedate DESC 
limit 0,1
```

If there's a specific GID you want, you could do:

```
select wp_ngg_gallery.name, wp_ngg_pictures.filename
from wp_ngg_gallery, wp_ngg_pictures
where wp_ngg_pictures.galleryid = wp_ngg_gallery.gid
and wp_ngg_gallery.gid = $gid
order by wp_ngg_pictures.imagedate DESC 
limit 0,1
```

(The $gid is valid if you're query is a string in PHP, you didn't say, though, if that's what you're using)

It's not clear if wp_ngg_pictures.galleryid is a foreign key to wp_ngg_gallery.gid but it's the most likely choice given the info you supplied. If it's not (if you can have galleries with no images), you might want to modify the other guy's query (using the outer join) by adding `and wp_ngg_gallery.gid = $gid` to it.

Comment: Just added AND wpp_ngg_gallery.gid = [supplied number] and this worked!

Answer (score 3):

Let me know how / if this works. If you dump both of those tables (out of phpMyAdmin) in a SQL format I will create local databases and give it a run myself (assuming this doesn't work).

```
SELECT
    `wp_ngg_gallery`.`name`,
    `wp_ngg_pictures`.`filename`
FROM
    `wp_ngg_gallery`
    LEFT JOIN
        `wp_ngg_pictures`
    ON
        `wp_ngg_gallery`.`gid` = `wp_ngg_pictures`.`galleryid`
ORDER BY
    `wp_ngg_pictures`.`imagedate` DESC
LIMIT
    0,1;
```

This is assuming you need a JOIN. It could probably be done with a decent `GROUP BY` statement.

Comment: This is good, but I need to specify the GID. For example - Where GID = 3

Comment: +1 for using an outer join -- not assuming a gallery has any pictures.

Comment: @Wes: Then add a `WHERE wp_ngg_gallery.gid = [GID]` to the query. @Bill: Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want it for *multiple*  gids (choose the other options for a single one):

```
SELECT gid,name, a.filename
FROM wp_ngg_gallery
JOIN  wp_ngg_pictures a
ON a.galleryid = gid 
LEFT JOIN wp_ngg_pictures b
ON a.galleryid = gid 
AND b.imagedate > a.imagedate
WHERE b.galleryid IS NULL
AND gid IN (1,2,3)
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing there, but it doesn't sort by `imagedate` and you're using a static `IN ()` method. Assume he wants to pair all records.

Comment: You need `WHERE b.galleryid IS NULL`, not `a.gallaryid IS NULL`, but this is the solution I use for the dozens of questions I've answered with the `greatest-n-per-group` tag.  However, the OP didn't say they needed to search for multiple gids, so their question can be answered with a simpler query.

Comment: @Bill : oops, fixed :) (and that was the reason I explicitly said only to use if for multples) @Josh K: ye unbeliever, go forth and test, and let there be much rejoicing in new knowledge.